# Reading Outlook Emails in Shared Folder - Python

Tags: python, outlook, win32com

I have been using the below code to access a public folder in Outlook:

```
import win32com.client
import datetime


outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(18).Folders.Item("xxxxx")
messages = inbox.Items
date = datetime.date.today()


subject = "xxxxxxx"

for message in messages:
    if subject in message.subject and date in message.senton.date():
     print(message.senton.time())
```

However, our Outlook has been moved from an Exchange server to the cloud and public folders have been changed to shared folders (I think?). The above code no longer works and I get the below error:

```
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (4096, 'Microsoft Outlook', 'The attempted operation failed.  An object could not be found.', None, 0, -2147221233), None)
```

Is there any way to search emails from a shared mailbox?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`inbox = outlook.Folders("Name of Shared Folder").Folders.Item("xxxxx")`

Comment: Awesome! That seems to have worked, I have one more question though. I can't seem to download attachments from emails with the code I was previously using on the old folder. I have updated my question with the code to download attachments. Would you have any idea how?

Comment: okay never mind, I think I will post a separate question. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: You can use 

 `attachments = message.Attachments`

Then to test it works, print the name of the attachements:

`for i in range(attachments.Count):
 attachment = attachments.Item(i+1)
 print(attachment)`

Comment: Okay awesome, do you have any idea how to specify to download only excel attachments for example? And ignore pdfs etc?

Comment: I would recommend using the `find()` function on the string and look for ".xlsx" or ".pdf". Good luck!